# How to get rid of '\n' at the beginning of string

Tags: c, string

Here's the string char `temp[] = "\nHello";`

How to get rid of the `\n` at the beginning of the string?

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: do you mean remove it from the variable `temp` or do you mean make a new variable without the \n?

Comment: If you already know it is at the beginning...what's stopping you?

Comment: Downvoted for apparent lack of effort in researching/solving this before posting here, and downvoted for lack of effort in writing this question.

Comment: Yes, *gang downvoting*, that is the perfect way to help someone learn how to use S.O. -- c'mon...

Comment: if a new variable - is it to be on the stack, dynamic,...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use standard C function `memmove`. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char temp[] = "\nHello";

    if (temp[0] == '\n')
    {
        memmove(temp, temp + 1, strlen(temp));
    }

    puts(temp);
}
```

Comment: Just want to mention for posterity that `memmove()` is the correct function here, _not_ `memcpy()` or `strcpy()` (as another answer tried), which cause undefined behavior when copying between overlapping objects.

Answer (score 1):

In C? You can effectively do this by:

```
char* c = "\nnoodle";
if (c[0] == '\n')
  c++;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to mention that I want also to check if there's \n at the at the beginning of the string..

Comment: @Saga How about an `if`?

Comment: put that in the question

Comment: This is fine if `c` is a pointer to a string literal, but will not work if `c` is an array (as OP has in posted code) since arrays are not modifiable lvalues.

Answer (score -3):

And what about....

```
    if (temp[0]=='\n') strcpy(temp, temp+1);
```

Comment: `strcpy` usually comes with `__restrict` keyword, witch makes your construction an undefined behavior.

Comment: [Using `strcpy()` to copy between overlapping objects causes undefined behavior.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.2.3p2)